# Core Data Save Error (NSValidationErrorKey, Cocoa error 1570) saving NSDate

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsdate

I'm getting an error with saving to a Core data object in Xcode.

Xcode says that the error is in the NSDate variable 'datum' but I have tried almost everything.
Error is:

```
2011-07-12 18:01:29.068 WeekLijstje[3205:207] Core Data Save Error
NSValidationErrorKey    datum
NSValidationErrorPredicate  (null)

NSValidationErrorObject
<DagLijst: 0x6e2fcd0> (entity: DagLijst; id: 0x6e2fd30 <x-coredata:///DagLijst/t99F423FC-AAE9-4692-9264-EF0FF7A020572> ; data: {
    Voedsel = nil;
    datum = nil;
    hoeveelheid = 0;
    punten = 0;
})
NSLocalizedDescription:The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)
```

A small code snipet:

```
        DagLijst *newDaglijst = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DagLijst" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        NSDate *selDatum = [NSDate date];
        newDaglijst.punten = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:10];
        newDaglijst.hoeveelheid = [NSNumber numberWithInt:100];
        newDaglijst.Voedsel = geselecteerdVoedsel;
        newDaglijst.datum = selDatum;
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![newDaglijst.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
...
```

Also the class of the DagLijst object:

```
@interface DagLijst : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * datum;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * punten;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * hoeveelheid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Voedsel *Voedsel;

@end
```

So you can see that I put an NSDate into the 'datum' variable. But on execution I still get an error.

Answer (score 154):

The cocoa error `1570` means that mandatory fields are not filled in.
In this case, your have two attribues that are `nil` : `Voedsel` and `datum`.

I see in your code :

```
newDaglijst.Voedsel = geselecteerdVoedsel;
newDaglijst.datum = selDatum;
```

Check that `geselecteerdVoedsel` and `selDatum` are not nil or that they are overreleased and finish to be nil. 
If they are optional data (but I don't think so), define them as optional in coredata.

Hope this help,

Comment: in my case, the child context has proper data, whereas the parent context, when it tries to save has no data..!! Everything is nil!!
How can I ensure that the data is getting reflected to the parent ?
Link to my question is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666178/multi-context-coredata-with-threads/19683462?noredirect=1#19683462

Comment: I ran into this same problem trying to save `NO` in an `NSNumber` that we used as a boolean value. I wracked my brain for an hour before realizing I needed to use `@NO`

Comment: Same here: tried to write 0 to a non-optional `NSNumber` attribute, setting it `nil`. Assign `@0` instead.

Answer (score 3):

as Michael A said. Check your attributes value are not nil.
There are 2 alternatives to get rid of these error.
Case 1:If 2 attributes are Required

If the 2 attributes are required attributes then it is mandatory to check the values you are passing are not nil,It may happens sometimes,If u want to get out of these error u have to give default values for those attributes in attributes inspector of your Entity in data Model

Case 2:
Set those attributes to optional in attribute inspector by selecting the check mark of optional.

Me too struggled for days to know these error.
Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Your logging would look like this:

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: 
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1560 "(null)" UserInfo={NSDetailedErrors=(
...
```

It means you have an uncommitted change for one (or more) property of a entity, in which you told it is NOT optional, but you left it optional.

To find out which entity you failed to set value for a property, look for this in your logging:

```
UserInfo={NSValidationErrorObject=<YOURENTITYISHERE: ...>
```

To find out the property, search for:

```
NSValidationErrorKey=YOURPROPERTYISHERE
```

Somewhere in your code you forget to set a value for that property for the given entity.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I copied entities from other `xcdatamodeld` file.
They lost inverse attributes, so that was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Not really related with date, but with the error, I share it as this question has more views:

In my case, I was setting a `BOOL` property directly as `YES` or `NO`, but you should use

> NSNumber numberWithBOOL

in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

To reinforce Michael's answer, you can check your Entity properties in the inspector. One of your items may be accidentally considered Optional, or not. Or, if you're like me, your "Delete Rule" might have been set to "Nullify", which made my Entity's relationship property `Nil` at runtime. Because my object-to-be-deleted had a One-To-Many relationship with some other objects, it prevented the parent objects from being deleted. Changing it to `Cascade` solved the problem.

[Entity Inspector - Delete Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsKOc.png)